# Report Portal does not receive the test results from Test Cafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I wish to have the results from testcafe in report portal.  I am running in a linux AWS environment. I am trying to use the reporter https://github.com/danitseitlin/reportportal-testcafe-plugin . When running the test, I get a message "Report Portal launch : function link() { [native code] }. No launch gets shown in report portal. What does this message mean, and how can I fix it.

At command line this is the command I am running.
/usr/bin/node //hone/wally/testcafe/node_modules/testscafe.js chrome test.js --reporter=reportportal --rdomain=http://reportportal.svcs.aws:8080/ --rtoken=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx --rlaunch=wally_test
added --rproject=wally_test

Comment: It seems that you missed a required argument (--rproject) https://github.com/danitseitlin/reportportal-testcafe-plugin

Comment: Thank you Andrey, I made the adjustments.  However I still do not get launch listed in report portal.  Still  get a message "Report Portal launch : function link() { [native code] }.

Comment: You need to [open a new issue](https://github.com/danitseitlin/reportportal-testcafe-plugin/issues/new) in the reporter repository with all the required information to reproduce this behavior.